# Deleted questions and answers based on chat?

Tags: discussion, support, stack-overflow, vote-to-close, vote-to-delete

I am wondering why a user will take all my answers at a time and ask on chat to delete the whole question.

Today I got 4 answers downvoted and then deleted because a user asked other users on chat to delete those questions.

Is this behavior ok? I mean, sure, it closes the question, maybe deletes my answer, but taking all my answered questions and delete them? All my answers with over 10 votes, no other answers, just those.

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686561/split-a-string-at-every-nth-position-with-php
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12578073/why-my-code-has-error
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12157715/format-php-array

Comment: What chat was this? You have a permalink?

Comment: SO PHP Chat ... with the delv plugin ..

Comment: I can't speak for whether those questions deserve to be deleted. But if they were specifically targeting you, then this doesn't seem right.

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5715567#5715567, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5715574#5715574, http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5715583#5715583

Comment: they were only targeting me, no other delv

Comment: I have 3 jobs at this moment, and I simply love SO and all it's features, I like to help others, but it's frustrating when I get home and I see my answers deleted, and SO is time consuming ..

Comment: Sorry, but those questions were all too localized and deserved deletion IMO.

Comment: OK, i believe that. But why targeting me and deleted based on chat ? And they are not that localized ..

Comment: Why he didn't ask to delete this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12821891/php-print-r-and-var-dump-returning-1, he asked only close: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5716089#5716089 it is same as localized as those were. He was clearly targeting me

Comment: Stop answering crap questions and the problem will go away.

Comment: I too don't mind answering basic questions, but I try to be sure my answers are very substantial and will contain enough good content so that someone will think twice about deleting the question just because the answer is a very through explanation. These questions appear to be very basic, and your answers all appear to just be links to the function needed and the code needed to solve the problem, with almost no explanations at all.

Comment: @Mihai sometimes a good answer can save a question from deletion. But would you seriously argue that was the case in any of these examples? I'm not saying the answers were *bad,* not at all. They sure helped the OP. But are they artifacts that should be saved for future generations? That have no better explanation elsewhere? Nah. The questions were textbook "too localised", and the answers didn't change that.

Comment: @MihaiIorga Two of your answers simply say "use LinkToFunctionName();" followed by a code sample, and the third says "double equals `if (($a%3 == 0) && ($a%5 == 0)) {`". I'm just saying there's nothing wrong with answering basic questions, but if your answer is basic as well then there's a higher chance of the question getting closed/deleted at some point.

Comment: Yes, I was pointing what I am using to achieve the OP's goal. But they weren't just links, they were full answers with solution

Comment: Making comments such as "are you talking just to say something" (the one you made to @Rachel) is rude.  This is not tolerated, to the point where it's [codified in the faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#benice).  You might not like what she is trying to say, but she *is* trying to help, just as most other people here are.  You would do well to remember that in your interactions with everyone here.

Comment: Also, no one targeted *you*.  They targeted the questions.  The answers were not deleted because they were yours, but there isn't a mechanism to keep answers undeleted while questions are deleted (it doesn't make sense, if you think of it).

Comment: @casperOne, i'm sorry for the comment to Rachel, but I was getting to frustrated and she just made more flame. About the questions if you read the last comments bellow and what Gordon said on chat was really targeting me, if there was only one at a time I wouldn't said anything. I was wrong. But I'm 100% he was targeting me. I'm sorry I even said anything. Please delete the question.

Comment: @Bart I'm not that good at English but I thing 2 vocals should not meet coming from 2 different words. Or am I wrong?

Comment: See [Is asking others for a close-vote appropriate?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/120275/170584)  This has been covered before.

Comment: @MihaiIorga It's more about the sound of them. User is pronounced with a 'y' sound at the beginning. Making it "a user" instead of "an user". The inverse goes for "hour" where the "h" is silent, resulting in "an hour".

Comment: No one person is ever targeted. It has never happened. If it gets suggested in chat, it is in jest. The practice of soliciting close/delete votes is contentious enough as it is (see various questions on meta, I can't find the links off hand) - we make sure that we play within the rules, because at the end of the day we are trying to help the site. Persecuting any particular user(s) is, if anything, hurting it. If you feel you are being targeted (and you aren't), chances are the reason is because you keep getting involved with sub-standard questions.

Comment: @Bart ... didn't knew about that :)

Comment: @DaveRandom I never said Gordon "deleted" my answers for no reason, there is always a reason, and his reason was fair enough. I fact my original question had nothing related about that questions or him. I just asked if it is ok, someone else modified my question and added links and then all this started. Like I said, he targeted me and not for bad reasons, I'm guessing he "reviewed" my answers and deciced to delete all questions. I didn't get frustrated because he and other 2 deleted my answers, the "targeting" on chat was frustrating,  when he said: DELETE, that's what happened in next 5 min.

Comment: Who ever answered in comments you all got wrong the idea of the question and you changed it's purpose in what way you wanted. My question was WHY targeting and not the quality of the posts. And you started to delete more questions where I was involved. I've taken each one of you and looked at your answers, you all got same answer principle as I had. So why aren't you starting to delete your own answered questions?

Comment: It's very simple. See a crap question or answer. Vote to close. Click the profile of the associated user and review the quality of other recent questions/answers. The odds are if there is no effort put in one, there will be no effort put in others. It actually makes it very easy to clean up some of the garbage on SO when users make consistently bad posts. We see people doing it every day, answering for the sake of building rep instead of closing as a duplicate or too localised, or whatever. If you make good posts, and make an effort to keep SO clean, you're never going to be a "victim" of this

Answer (score 26):

The questions linked to in the chat conversation were garbage. The very definition of the kind of content we don't want here, and what delete votes are for. Example:

> I have this link
>
> ```
>   http://xxx.com/u.php?link=http://xx.com/MZ_THUMB.jpg&amp;w=120&amp;h=120
> ```
>
> I want to replace this part: `&amp;w=120&amp;h=120`  with a blank so i would have just
>
> ```
>     http://xxx.com/u.php?link=http://xx.com/MZ_THUMB.jpg
> ```
>
> I've tried with str_replace but no luck. Any ideas? Thanks!

As to targeting questions that you have answered - I don't think anyone is attacking you personally; but even if it were the case, then it's just you answered a couple of exceedingly localized and basic questions that someone maybe found through your profile. I don't know, but even that would not be a problem in my book. Answering crap is not a sin as such, but I've arrived in the camp that says answering these kinds of questions encourages the asking of even more of them, and that's a bad thing - especially in the PHP tag. Deleting this stuff is actually quality control.

If you do not want to risk answering a question that may be deleted, and losing the rep associated with it, **refrain from answering it.**

Comment: Like I said, I have no problem, I answer and I do other things in same time. My question: why an user is targeting me and ONLY delete my answered questions and not other? Check this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5716089#5716089, same thing

Comment: @Mihai you didn't answer the question you link to? As said, maybe someone looked into your profile and saw you had answered some extremely basic questions. It's still not really targeting *you*, but the bad question. I know that particular user cares very much about quality, and does not discriminate by person.

Comment: @MihaiIorga The PHP chat has tons of questions passed around like this every day. They're not specifically targeting you nor are they doing it maliciously.

Comment: Do you see other delv ? Ok ... I believe you high reputation users are close .. I was sure I will be only pushed away ..

Comment: @MikeB did you see this: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/5715567#5715567 ? Are you seeing other questions with delv where I'm not involved near that hour ?

Comment: @MihaiIorga 632 other delv-pls tags at a glance http://chat.stackoverflow.com/search?q=delv-pls&room=11

Comment: @MikeB 632 from June ..

Comment: @Pekka .. and now you are mocking me ... exactly like I said ..

Comment: And to answer this answer, He posted his problem, he posted what he tried and asked for other ideas ...

Comment: @Mihai I am mocking you because of your baseless accusation that I'm taking the user's side because we are somehow "close" and not because I think he was *doing the right thing.*

Comment: You misunderstood. I didn't said he wan't right. I said why targeting me, you are clearly loosing the point

Comment: @MihaiIorga Nobody is specifically targeting you. From leafing through the chat log of the PHP room (where I don't usually come) I find many many more instances that don't target you. That yours might have been relatively grouped might be because a couple of similar situations were found in your history. That's all. I don't see any big conspiracy here.

Comment: @Mihai maybe he was indeed going through your answers and saw some that were answers to bad questions. But so what? Even that is targeting the *questions*, not you. That user once close voted and delete voted one of [my top voted questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1812472). He is `cv-pls`ing and delete-voting stuff all the time. He's not discriminating against anyone specially, he just cares about quality in the PHP tag.

Comment: @Pekka "ONCE" and not 3 at a time, and they were 4 deleted from him. and he was 100% targeting me.

Comment: You're making an issue because they were *justifiably* deleted all at once instead of one at a time.. really?

Comment: exactly, why targeting?

Comment: @MihaiIorga Even if he was, you're  going to get nothing out of going ballistic over this. Even if he targeted you 100%, which I doubt, then the closure and deletion was still valid, as you agree. That's it. Move on. Spend you energy on good answers or questions. We need you there. ;)

Comment: Just to add something, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817790/how-to-separate-php-and-html/12817900#12817900, I've answered this question from my experience and he deleted the question, today, on chat, with delv. And then all started, he commented on that answer.

Comment: As an aside: I've had very highly-rated questions deleted by those very same people. If I had a problem with it I discussed it with them and they raised some very good issues that justified deletion. This is how these matters should be handled, not posting to Meta.

Comment: as a side note @MikeB clearly you dind't .. sorry

Comment: Well, I think this discussion is good to have here for future reference.

Comment: I really like this part of your answer: "**answering these kinds of questions encourages the asking of even more of them, and that's a bad thing**". I think it explains clearly a too common problem with [tag:php] questions on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Thank you, Pekka. These words of yours ring like a symphony in my ears!

Comment: @Gordon, did you ever looked back to your first answered questions? You know that I started to answer on SO about 1 month ago right? And you asked to delete some of my first answered questions.

Comment: Same goes for you @Pekka, did you ever looked back ? In fact same goes for anyone here, no exceptions!

Comment: @MihaiIorga A lot of people already explained to you in great and correct detail why your answers got deleted. I had appreciated it if you had asked me directly in chat instead of making such a pointless fuss here. I am surprised that after one week, you finally ask me directly. It's disconcerting. Apparently you still think this is personal. I am sorry, but I cannot help you get over that.

Comment: Wow. This "discussion" is still continuing? Should we all post meta questions now because you are "targeting" us with your comment? But seriously stop taking offense when crappy questions get deleted. It's not you it's just the crappy questions you choose to answer.

Comment: By the way, congratulations, you have the 150000th meta post - http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/150000 `:P`

Comment: @Doorknob hah!!! Funny.

Answer (score 19):

I would recommend for you to take a hard look at the type of questions you tend to answer:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12818431/else-if-nightmare
- [json string to php to mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12815154/json-string-to-php-to-mysql)
- [get specific ip adress from a string using php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813968/get-specific-ip-adress-from-a-string-using-php)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813602/why-this-error-notice-use-of-undefined-constant
- [how to assign php array values to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12813580/how-to-assign-php-array-values-to-javascript-array)
- [Representing php associative array equivalent to javascript array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12801792/representing-php-associative-array-equivalent-to-javascript-array)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797209/how-start-and-end-php-session-using-a-link
- [Basic PHP SQL Query not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797617/basic-php-sql-query-not-working)
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12778600/strict-standards-error-on-stdclass-object
- [Best way to add values to array (append an item or array_merge())](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12796453/best-way-to-add-values-to-array-append-an-item-or-array-merge)

It's not that people are targeting you. You just provide a convenient "database" of worst questions that SO can offer. I cannot blame people for using your profile as a good tool for cleaning up [php](/questions/tagged/php) content.

Comment: The act of answering (easy) low quality questions just for the sake of the reputation gain, is commonly referred to as "Rep-whoring". Being a "rep-whore" would lead to exactly such circumstances. The lesson to be learnt, instead of providing answers to questions already answer, help moderate the site by closing them.

Comment: I would recommend you doing that for all users. The question was why targeting and you are doing just that. Was never about the quality of the questions or answers.

Comment: And as a side node, please take a hard look back to questions you answered.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha like [faq](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/faq#benice) says I would recommend to start respecting, calling me names is not respectful.

Comment: @MihaiIorga: I haven't called you in any names, and I apologize if you were offended. I'm simply relaying the information of how people who answer easy-duplicate-localized type questions are viewed.

Comment: @MihaiIorga: All (most) of us were "rep-whoring" back in our early days. Innocent answering for these easy questions, thinking we're helping people. But as you gain reputation and veterancy at the site, you should start noticing patterns. Questions which are asked over and over again, and should not be answered (as you are feeding the help vampires), but instead should be closed as a duplicate of an appropriate question. You are a higher rep user, and apparently haven't gotten over that stage yet. That is why you were spotted and are "on the radar" of folks from the PHP chat.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha, when I posted those answers I was low-rep ... so your argument is invalid.

Comment: @MihaiIorga: My point exactly. These questions have been answered before numerous times, and/or could be very easily answered if OP simply takes a glance to the manual. Hence, they are inappropriate, and even though the answers took popularity, it doesn't mean that the question is good.

Answer (score 9):

Is it okay to go to chat and ask high rep users to delete content, yes. That is perfectly acceptable. You need a significant amount of reputation to vote to delete answers/questions, and it takes three non-moderators to do it. The entire purpose of those two restrictions is so that people who don't know what should be deleted won't be deleting content, and that one person's opinion (unless that opinion has been vetted by the community through moderation elections) will not be binding for such an important action.

The users will still be thinking for themselves; they will decide whether or not the content actually deserves to be deleted, and they can be trusted to take the appropriate action.  Bringing a bunch of questions/answers to their attention (if done in good faith) is not a bad thing, even if some of those questions aren't delete worthy.

So bringing it up in chat isn't an issue, that only really leaves the question of, when looked at in isolation, should each of those answers have been deleted.  It seems that the general consensus here is that they should be.  If they weren't then you could bring them to the attention of others in just the same way that someone else brought them up in chat to ask for un-delete votes.  If such votes would be justified you would likely get them.