# Sanity check on NAA flag?

Tags: discussion, flags, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I was wondering if a sanity check might be possible regarding [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22215321/785241), which I flagged as NAA.

Per my understanding of NAA, as well as the text under the flag itself, it is reserved for answers which 'do not attempt to answer the question'.  I personally don't believe that this answer attempts to answer the question, which asks how to generate an html table from a mysql query.. not how to retrieve form values the 'proper' way.

In case it is relevant, here is the question title, and the answer text(also in case they are deleted):

**Question title:** Displaying a php array (made by sql) as a table on html

**Answer text:** When you get values from a form always use $_POST

(and then a code example showing how to use $_POST)

So.. am I wrong here?

Comment: And to be clear, I have read the duplicates of this, as well as most of the other questions about specific answers.  I still feel the need to ask, though.

Comment: Is it an answer of any kind?

Comment: From what you've posted, the answer doesn't seem to be relevant to the question.

Comment: it is also incorrect, but that's beside the point

Comment: @RobertHarvey In my opinion, I don't feel it is.  At best, its a comment on what type of variable retrieval should be used.

Comment: Appears to me to be NAA. Looks like a suggestion on what the OP currently is doing...not answering the question at-hand.

Comment: I'd say it's hard to tell what the question is actually about. Who is to say what the answerer thought the question was asking? (Apart from the newbie poster, who clearly admitted this was meant as a comment)

Comment: As a side note, I assume you closevoted the question, @Daedalus?

Comment: As it stands now I do believe this is not an answer. Under the [new guidelines](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224167/proposal-for-making-the-meaning-of-not-an-answer-flags-clearer) this to me seems like it would fall under the category "it is an attempt to communicate with some other user (should be a comment)" since it is a suggestion relative to the topic and not an answer directly to the question.

Comment: @JanDvorak I haven't voted to close yet as I'm still uncertain of how to vote in that regard.. though it likely could be voted to close as a duplicate, I just need to find the duplicate.  Otherwise, I don't agree with the current vote to close reasons as 'unclear what you're asking'.

Comment: @Daedalus: I cast the fifth close vote as "unclear what you are asking."

Comment: @TravisJ: You can say "it is an attempt to communicate with some other user (should be a comment) since it is a suggestion relative to the topic and not an answer directly to the question." in a custom flag.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I don't understand why you're telling me.  I stand by my disagreement with that reason per the question title.

Comment: @Daedalus: Fair enough.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here's the thing about Not an Answer flags: **The moderator dashboard does not display the question.**  That means that, if you're relying on question context to verify the veracity of your NAA flag, you risk getting your flag declined.

When an answer is flagged NAA, moderators expect to see something that doesn't look like an answer.  Something like:

1. I have a question...
2. @someUser: I think that...
3. I like turtles.
4. aj098243u5in (cat on keyboard)

The answer you flagged looks like an answer, and because moderators *do not evaluate answers for technical veracity,* there's no reasonable way that they can approve such flags on the basis of question content and answer context.  NAA flags are simply not designed to do that.

The only action a moderator can take on an NAA answer is to delete it, and a mod is not likely to delete an answer based on how good or bad it is, relative to the question asked.  The better remedy is to downvote and comment on the answer.

As always, if there's any doubt, **cast a custom moderator flag instead of the canned one, and explain the problem specifically.**

Comment: Maybe moderators should also verify the answer is at least somewhat related to the question topic (even if this leads to a feature-request for the mod tools to display the question)?

Comment: In this exact case, I am considering casting a delete vote on this answer. I *can* see both the question and answer and in that context it is clear this should be a comment on the question at best (the code is just the OPs code with the word Get replaced with Post). Is it incorrect for me to cast a delete vote here if a moderator would decline the flag? Or is it correct because the moderator may not have been able to review the entire context of the answer?

Comment: OK, a follow-up question: Since it's clearly NAA and the NAA flag clearly doesn't suffice, is it OK to flag such answers as "other - post is unrelated to the question"?

Comment: @TravisJ: You're perfectly within your rights to cast a delete vote, and I encourage you to do so.  But that doesn't involve a moderator.  Moderators shouldn't be handling situations that the community can handle themselves.

Comment: @JanDvorak: You'd still be asking mods to evaluate the answer *based on whether its technical content is good or bad.*  We don't do that.  That's what downvotes are for.

Comment: @RobertHarvey If the only possibility is to delete the answer, then I assume the 'convert to comment tool' is no longer viable?  Also, given what you said, I personally believe that the question context should be visible.  What if someone asks a Python question and is answered with a javascript answer?

Comment: ... in which case, should "looks like an answer, but is off-topic" be flagged as VLQ, so that they are pushed to the VLQ queue? Since they clearly should be deleted and mods don't want to have to understand the question.

Comment: @Daedalus: See my edit.

Comment: @JanDvorak If you really, really, really want a moderator involved (as I can see there's no reason to involve us here), then use a custom flag and explain the exact problem. "This is an I like cats answer. The question mentions felines, but the answer is in another ballpark where dogs are the majority animal".

Comment: @RobertHarvey - I see, I think that the distinction you are making is a fundamental misunderstanding that I have had. Just to make sure I fully understand this (sorry to badger) -- it is not the moderators job to review technical correctness of content, but the community is more than welcome to (i.e. with down votes or delete votes when applicable)?

Comment: @TravisJ: That's right.

Comment: So, the best solution for off-topic answers is to spam the relevant chat rooms with delvote-pleases?

Comment: @JanDvorak: I do that all the time in the Whiteboard chat room, if I think the site is better served by the answer just being gone.  In the Wild West days of Programmers, I cast a lot of flags.  But I was recently asked by the mods there to cast fewer flags, and give the review queues a chance to do their work.

Comment: @JanDvorak Whatever floats your "Don't-involve-the-moderators-because-it's-a-technical-discussion-and-we're-just-monkeys-with-guns-in-our-hands" boat.

Comment: I'm sad to say I can't find that particular image for this discussion.

Comment: fewer flags, or fewer other flags? Does a very low score suffice to push the question into the VLQQ?

Comment: As another side question... has the PHP room already been asked to delvote? :-)

Comment: @JanDvorak I asked for a sanity check there, but when it looked like I was being ignored, I gave up and asked here instead.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker: I tried doing a Google Image Search, but only found this: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Vazm9.jpg

Comment: Last time I checked, not an answer meant not an answer (in the sane world). If the answer is totally unrelated, it's as much of an answer as "I like turtles".

Comment: @Jan: [Apparently, yes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120275/is-asking-others-for-a-close-vote-appropriate), the right thing to do here is to delvote and (exaggerating only slightly) find two friends to do the same. It's a *very* different cultural norm as compared to, say, [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Canvassing), and one I'm still not entirely comfortable with, even though I do understand why it makes sense, given the differences in subject matter and decision-making processes. (AFAIK, few if any political lobbies try to actively bias Stack Overflow content.)

Comment: @bjb568: "Moderators don't evaluate content for technical accuracy" trumps "This isn't an answer because it doesn't answer the question."

Comment: @IlmariKaronen: In practice, this happens very rarely, and when it does, it does because some tag is getting overrun with newbie questions.

Comment: @Robert A wrong answer "You can fix the problem by deleting all your code" is "Moderators don't evaluate content for technical accuracy". The same answer when the question is "which is faster?" has nothing to do with technical inaccuracies.

Comment: @bjb568: That's a specious argument.  We can tell when someone is being a troll.

Comment: @Robert It was an example. "You can fix the problem by doing `throw 'there is no reason to throw'`" is technical inaccuracy. The same example is not a technical inaccuracy when talking about "which is faster?", it's NAA.

Comment: @bjb568 Use a NAA flag if you must.  Just don't expect moderators to try and figure out why you flagged it if it clearly looks like an answer.

Comment: @Robert I'm not talking about whether I should flag it now. I'm talking about whether the mod tools should be changed in the future.

Comment: @bjb568: Why?  You already have the ability to explain in a custom flag why you think the answer is actively harmful to the site, and should be forcibly removed by a mod.

Comment: @Robert 2 things. 1) Why should it be only for mods? How about public review queues? 2) Why not make everything a custom flag?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by #1.  Canned flags are supposed to provide a bit of guidance on how to flag, although, given the pedantry that surrounds the NAA flag (a flag that I consider ridiculously simple to comprehend), I have wondered myself about #2.  See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224167/proposal-for-making-the-meaning-of-not-an-answer-flags-clearer

Comment: Do you see comments on a flagged answer? I generally explain my issues with a post in a comment (so the poster can see what's wrong with it, not just the mod) and only then flag it.

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The poster should be able to see your comment on a deleted post.  There's an inscription placed on the deleted answer to the effect of "Why was your post deleted? See here: link", which the poster would not be able to see otherwise.

Comment: @RobertHarvey I wanted to know if you see the comment in the mod tool. For example I post a comment explaining why this is not an answer, and then add a NAA flag without further elaboration. Should I copy the reason from the comment into the flag instead, to account for the deficient mod tool?

Comment: @CodesInChaos: The moderator flag should always contain all of the information the moderator needs to make a decision.  You can put a comment below the post, but it requires an extra step for mods to see it (the answer has to be expanded in the moderator dashboard), and your comments to the moderator are not the only things that might appear in the comments. If you want a moderator to see it, copy/paste it into a custom flag.